# Switch statement doesn't work in android project

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android Dev. I've just met this problem with a switch case statement on a string :

```
String str = "Hello";
switch (str) {
    case "Hello":
       System.out.println("case 1");break;
    default:
       System.out.println("default");break;
}
```

Eclispse Logs :

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted Home.java
```

So i'm going to Project properties --> Java Compiler and i set the JDK to 1.7 and applied it. But now eclipse tails me to fix properties which comeback to 1st problem...

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

How can i fix it to use my switch case ?

Thanks

Comment: you can fix only using an integer to switch

Comment: Right click on your project in  your eclipse. Goto Android tools. Click Fix Project Properties.

Comment: You can not pass string in switch statement

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html. check the java docs

Comment: Click project in your eclipse project->properties->java compiler-> and change the compiler compilence level  1.7

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass numeric value or character value in switch statement.
Ex.

```
char str = 'A';
switch (str) {
    case 'A':
       System.out.println("case 1");break;
    default:
       System.out.println("default");break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes switch statements with the `String` class are introduces in Java 1.7. But Android works with 1.6 sorry. Check the docs for what types you can use. I don't know the case but `Enums` and switch statements works really well

Answer (score 0):

Lower your compiler version to 1.6 in eclipse properties. Android doesn't support all of 1.7 yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make explicit the case in the switch you can use enums

```
public enum helloEnum {
    HELLO, HOLA, CIAO
}


public class EnumTest {
    helloEnum mHello;

    public EnumTest(helloEnum mHello) {
        this.mHello = mHello;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        switch (mHello) {
            case HELLO:
                System.out.println("hello");
                break;

            case HOLA:
                System.out.println("hola");
                break;

            case CIAO
                System.out.println("ciao");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("hello");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```